# A list of downloaded files names in google colabarotary

Tags: python-3.x, google-colaboratory

[image]

How can i get all file names of downloaded files in google colaboratory

Answer (score 2):

The default working directory of a Colab notebook is `/content`, so you can use `os.listdir` to get a list of the names of the entries in `/content`:

```
import os
DIR = "/content"

# if you want to list all the contents in DIR
entries = [entry for entry in os.listdir(DIR)]

# if you want to list all the files in DIR
entries = [entry for entry in os.listdir(DIR) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(DIR, entry))]
```

Then you can use a loop to print them:

```
for entry in entries:
    print(entry)
```

---

If you don't need to store this list in a variable, you can also use a bash command (note the `!` at the start of the line):

```
# list all the contents in /content
!ls /content

# list all the files in /content (https://askubuntu.com/questions/811210/how-can-i-make-ls-only-display-files)
!ls -p | grep -v /
```